# How to fix undefined result in $scope select options array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and trying to set up a select dropbox field with options that are contained in an array, and added via an input box by the end user. I have the $scope successfully adding to the array, but the dropdown select box just shows "undefined" for all options.

I have looked for similar answers but none of them specifically address what my error is, or are using Angular 2+ which doesn't help.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="maidOfHonor" ng-model="name"
        ng-options="names.value as names.value for name in names">
</select>
```

```js
$scope.names = [
    {
        name: "Position Not Filled",
        value: "Position Not Filled"
    }
];
$scope.addName = function() {
    $scope.names.push({ name: this.party.addName, value: this.party.addName });
    console.log($scope.names);
}
```

Ideally, I would like whatever "name" that is added via the $scope.addName() function to be added to the dropdown select box as the value or the name, instead of undefined of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your issue is the `ng-options` syntax.

Instead of:

> ```
> ng-options="names.value as names.value for name in names"
> ```

Try

```
ng-options="name.value as name.name for name in names"
```

`name.value` is the value to get from or set to the `ng-model`.

`name.name` is the value to show as the option's text.

Note that the variables referenced start with `name`, rather than `names` as in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `ng-repeat` which is comparatively easier than `ng-options`

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3onmb9u4/3/)